# CSS3 slideshow without knowing the number of slides

Tags: css, animation, slideshow, css-transitions

Since the development of `CSS3`, there are growing attempts to create browser-based effects (transitions and animations) merely based on `CSS3` without using `JavaScript`. There are several examples of `CSS3`-based slideshows, but one thing is always lacking:

The common method for creating `CSS3` slideshow is to induce sequencing delay for each slide. Thus, we need to know the number of slides and add a `CSS` rule for each corresponding element.

I am curious if there is another method to cycle a `CSS3` slideshow without having the number of elements?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `starts-with` selector to avoid a rule for each corresponding element:

```
section[id^=slide]:target {
opacity: 1;
z-index: 1;
-moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
}

section[id^=slide]:target ~ section[id^=slide] {
-moz-transform: translate(110%, 0);
}
```

References:

- [Pure CSS Slides](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/demos/detail/pure-css-slides)