# Html page slider without a framework

Tags: html

[image]

How I can add the slider at bottom of a html page that similar to the image?One of main restriction that this page is loaded in Uiwebview  when the app is offline.I found lot of solution with jQueryMobile and other framework.So that  wanted pure html tag based solution.

Thank you for spending valuable time  to review this question

Comment: Why are you down voted even without putting a comment.Please tell mistakes in this question?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter. However, you needn't to be online to use javascript, and you can't implement such a UI without javascript, I am afraid.

Comment: I have know that for inter page communication javascript is essential component.But How we can include such a ui without using complex external libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the pure CSS3 solutions, such as these:

- [CSS3 slideshow without knowing the number of slides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266246/css3-slideshow-without-knowing-the-number-of-slides/19102258#19102258)
- [Swipe Me Responsive Slideshow](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/cssplay-swipe-me-mobile.html)